# Cramer's theorem for a precise normal asymptotic distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, density-function, asymptotics

I am working on a homework problem for my probability class:

(Cramer Application)

A. Let $X_1, X_2, ... X_n$ be a sample from a distribution with pdf $f(x;p) = q^xp$. Determine the MLE of $p$

Solution: I was able to do this straight from the definition of of the distribution and the log-likelihood. I get that $\hat{p} = (\bar{x} + 1)^{-1}$, no problem.

B. Use Cramer's theorem to obtain the precise normal asymptotic distribution of 
$\sqrt{n}(\hat{p} - p)$

This is where I am struggling. Is this the delta method? If so, is my function $(\bar{x} + 1)^{-1}$? $\bar{x}^{-1}$? Or just classic, taking $x^2$? And if it isn't the delta method what is the theorem being referenced? Has anyone ever been exposed to a problem like this?

EDIT: So it seems to me that this must be the Cramer-Rao variance identity, where

$Var(p) = \frac{1}{I(p)}$

Comment: There are several completely different results known as "Cramer's Theorem" (or "Cramér's Theorem"). To which one do you refer?

Comment: @whuber that's one of the issues that I am struggling with, I don't know, all we were told was the "Cramer Convergence Theorem"

Comment: It could be [Slutsky's Theorem](http://www.bauer.uh.edu/rsusmel/phd/sR-9.pdf), which sometimes is attributed to Harald Cramér. But if you don't know, why not ask your instructor or refer to your course materials?

Comment: Good edit. But that now changes your question - where does your problem currently lie? Or is it solved now?